# How to map shocks from VAR to news? (Academics)

Tags: research, asset-pricing

I am trying to map shocks from VAR to discount-rate and cash-flows news following the paper of [Campbell and Vuolteenaho (2004)](http://www.nber.org/papers/w9509.pdf). It is said that news are a linear combination of shocks from VAR at (t+1) (see the formula on the picture). However, that means that both news will be perfectly correlated just by construction, or do I miss something?

[image]

Maybe anybody did it before and can explain it?
Any help is very appreciated!